# Store total coin value using lowest amount of coins?

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to write a code that reflects the below instructions.

A method that takes two values; the value to exchange, and the coin type to exclude, and then return the minimum coins needed to exchange the for the total value, and return the output as a String. For example multiCoinCalculator (756,50) may return "the coins to exchange are : 3 x 200p, 1 x 100p, 0x50, 2 x 20p, 1 x 10p, with a remainder of 6p".

The code I have written here returns how much of each coin is needed to make that value.

```
public void multiCoinCalculator(int coin, int coinValue) {
System.out.println("The exchanged coins are: ");
for (int c : coinList) {
if ( c == coinValue) {
System.out.println("0 " + c + "p");
}

else {
    int result = (coin/c)*c;
    System.out.println(result/c + " " + c + "p. ");
    
}

}
```

When I enter 756 as coin value and 50 as excluded coin I get the following:

```
The exchanged coins are: 
3 200p. 
7 100p. 
15 50p. 
37 20p. 
75 10p.
```

Would it be possible to get any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void multiCoinCalculator(int coin, int coinValue) {
System.out.println("The exchanged coins are: ");
for (int c : coinList) {
if ( c == coinValue) {
System.out.println("0 " + c + "p");
}

else {
    int result = (coin/c);
    System.out.println(result + " " + c + "p. ");
    coin=coin%c
}
}
System.out.println("Remainder of ,"+ coin +"p. ")
```